# Is there t-SNE in WEKA?

Tags: weka, tsne

I want to use t-SNE in WEKA just for visualization purposes. I tried to look at the package manager but could not find any implementation of it.

Is there anything that I can do to achieve it?

Comment: Please mods don't vote to close this question anymore as it has already been successfully answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly no, there is not a T-SNE implementation for WEKA.

If you can install python packages in your environment, then you can use the `wekaPython` package (in WEKA's package manager) to run scikit-learn's T-SNE implementation on data you have loaded into WEKA. Use this code in the 'CPython Scripting' panel (which appears after successfully installing `wekaPython`):

```
X = py_data.iloc[:, :-1]
y = py_data.iloc[:, -1]

from sklearn.manifold import TSNE
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

tX = TSNE().fit_transform(X)

plt.scatter(tX[:, 0], tX[:, 1])
plt.show()
```